# Back-up of system partition image: must the UEFI partition be copied too?

Tags: partitioning, uefi

For the purpose of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1336290/925128) (asking how to backup and restore a ext4 uefi system partition) I have realized that the small UEFI partition might be needed too. Should we make a backup of both system and UEFI partitions when the purpose is to have a backup of the system as img? Is the old small UEFI partition image needed when restoring the system from its partition image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect to boot your backup, you should backup the UEFI partition also.  Its contents are pretty generic, but the file EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg is wired to your root's UUID and partition number, so unless you want to reinstall grub, you'll need that in your backup.

Comment: You also have settings in UEFI that use the GUID of the ESP. I do backup ESP, but really expect to do a full reinstall of grub to have correct UEFI entries & files in ESP. If knowledgeable, you can manually use efibootmgr to create new correct UEFI entry & edit /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg with correct UUID & drive, partition, but often easier just to reinstall grub.